# Write an SQL write on a List property

Tags: sql

I have the following tables Situation:

A **Blog** contains many Posts. A **Post** has an **Author**.

I want to write an SQL query that: returns all the unique blogs that have at least 3 posts by the author "Janet";

I am no sure how to do this as I usually work with EntityFramework. Any help would be great.

**EDIT

I tried this:

```
SELECT auth.name
FROM Blog blo 
LEFT JOIN Auth auth
WHERE blo.authname = "janet"
```

Comment: Homework? Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: And why you do not do it?

Answer (score 1):

`Select distinct Blogs from tblblogs,tblposts,tblauthor where tblblogs.id=tblposts.blogid and tblposts.id=tblauthor.postid and tblautor.name='Janet'
group by blogs
having count(tblposts.id)>=3`

This is a rough query because you didn't mention the table structure. If you want more elaboration, kindly mention table structure